# How to to change UI state based on Ctrl key state (pressed or not) applicationwise?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to change some buttons to alternate functions along with different names when Ctrl is pressed and holding down and revert to original state when Ctrl is released.

I tried added KeyUp, KeyDown and PreviewKeyUp on Main Page.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log($"MainPage.OnKeyDown( {e.Key} ) ");
}
```

but its not getting triggered unless my mouse is focusing on a text box.

Should I just use a DispatchTimer to actively monitor the Control key state? Doesn't sound like a good approach though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CoreWindow-events. They are handled anytime the window has active focus.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_Pressed;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_Pressed;

bool ControlHoldDown = false;

private void CoreWindow_Pressed(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{
    ControlHoldDown = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);
    Debug.WriteLine("CTRL: " + ControlHoldDown);
}
```